# iOS Making Two Views Cover Full View

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, autolayout

I am trying to make my two sub views cover the width of the main view. Currently Day One becomes wider and Day Two stays the same and does not become wider. They both have the same layout constraints so I don't see the issue. Any solution to this?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Remove width constraint of view one and make Equal-width constraint between the 2 views by control-drag from view1 to view2 and select **Equal-widths**

Answer (score 1):

Add one more constraint that will tell them to have the same width.

Programmatically:

```
dayOneView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: dayTwoView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
```

In storyboards control drag from `Day One View` to `Day Two View` and select `Equal Widths`.

Without this the autolayout has no chance to know that you want those two views to have the same size.

Also, I think when you add it, you won't need the constraint `width >= 154` on those views.

Comment: How do I add this? Do I declare the views and place it into the viewdidload method?

Comment: @CurtisBoylan no, that's a programmatic way of creating constraints.. in storyboard, control drag from one view to the other and select `Equal Widths`